# Ms access SQL updating

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi guys, I'm quite new to SQL and I have the following question.
 I have one table with two columns named `student_Type` and `Fees`. I need to update the `Fees` column with values 5000 and 10000 where student_Type is = HomeStudent and Student_Type is = Overseas. I tried the following

```
UPDATE Student_Types
SET Fees= 5000,Fees=10000
WHERE Student_Type = 'HomeStudent' and 'Oversea';
```

I get duplication error because I have set same column twice. How can I get around this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way

```
UPDATE Student_Types
SET Fees= IIF(Student_Type = 'HomeStudent', 5000, 10000)
WHERE Student_Type IN ('HomeStudent','Oversea');
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no real need to do it in ONE query, so why bother with `IIF`?

```
UPDATE Student_Types
SET Fees = 5000
WHERE Student_Type = 'HomeStudent';

UPDATE Student_Types
SET Fees = 10000
WHERE Student_Type = 'Oversea';
```